# What's the meaning of stock?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

I am not sure if we say "stock build" or "stock". It seems to be a noun, but it seems to be used as a noun adjective in certain case, so I was wondering what's the correct and idiomatic way of using the word.

> Is this car a custom build or a stock?
>
> Is this a custom build or a stock build?
>
> It's a 98 Toyota Camry custom build, not a stock build, because of the
>   custom wing.
>
> It's a custom build car, it's not a stock.

Comment: In the US, we would not say "a stock". We would simply say "it's (not) stock".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this car a custom build or a stock build?

This is correct, 100% of the time.

> Is this car a custom build or a stock?

Speakers in live conversations may omit words if already said in the sentence, especially if the repetitive word is at the end of the sentence, if context/conversation is active enough where the listener will know to "fill in" the blank.

This is called [conversational ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/ellipsis).  The speaker in this example said "stock" but meant "stock build" and expected the listener to fill that in mentally.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a noun, just a plain old adjective. The difference is that it's modifying the word after it versus modifying the phrase before it.  1 and 4 are incorrect uses, 2 and 3 are correct. Something 'is stock' or 'is a stock build'. Throw in a color if there's ever a question. 'a green car' or 'it is green'.